# Php not receiving values from html form

Tags: php, html

In the following code, data from html form is not received by php variables. The code directly executes if-else statement without waiting for input.

```
<?php
if(mysql_connect("localhost","root","")==false)
{
  die ("Connection Failed");
}
mysql_select_db("fb");
$id=$_POST["email"];
$pwd=$_POST["password"];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM admin WHERE id='$id' AND pass='$pwd'");
if($sql)
{
 die ("Login");
}
else
{
  die ("Failed");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
  <title>
    HTML Document Structure
  </title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />!-->
</head>
<body>

  <form method="POST">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="inset">
      <p>
        <label for="email">Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="p-container">
      <span>Forgot password ?</span>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Log in">
    </p>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I know this code is vulnerable to SQL injection but who care if its an home assignment. :)

Comment: `but who cares` everyone that doesn't want to give or be a bad example would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code directly executes if-else statement without waiting for input.

Then tell it to do those action after input.

```
if($_POST) {
    $id=$_POST["email"];
    $pwd=$_POST["password"];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM admin WHERE id='$id' AND pass='$pwd'");
    if($sql)
    {
     die ("Login");
    }
    else
    {
      die ("Failed");
    }
}
```

> I know this code is vulnerable to SQL injection but who care if its an home assignment.

Never give up security just because of the nature of the project. You'll fall into a trap, and then it will bite you later on in life. Make sure you secure your application irregardless of the project.

Comment: Thank you so much, and thats for the advice to. :)

Answer (score 4):

> *The code directly executes if-else statement without waiting for input.*

The reason being is that you have your entire code (HTML/PHP/SQL) inside one file with no conditional statement to control it.

Using your submit button's name element with `if(isset($_POST['Login']))` will fix that.

Another option would be to use two seperate files. One with your form and the other with the PHP/SQL and setting `action="handler.php"` for your form's action.

`<form method="POST">` is equivalent to `<form method="POST" action="">` (self).

```
<?php
if(mysql_connect("localhost","root","")==false)
{
  die ("Connection Failed");
}
mysql_select_db("fb");
$id=$_POST["email"];
$pwd=$_POST["password"];

if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$id' AND pass='$pwd'");
if($sql)
{
 die ("Login");
}
else
{
  die ("Failed");
}

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>
```

---

The following links will help you later on.

For passwords, [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus,  [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

- [**Always use error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) this will help you to debug code.

Plus, use `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` instead of just the way you have it now. It will signal the actual error, should there be any.